# Returning a value from a loop in Clojure

Tags: loops, google-maps, clojure, maps

I would like to the function `(string-place-typeII)` to return the value from `(calculate-distance-matrix)` like this: `{:distance "5 km" :duration "2 mins"}` on each loop or **better still** pass it to some variable enclosed in `{}` so I can return all of it at the end of the loop.

List of functions:

```
(defn get-placetypes
  ""
  []  (into-array (PlaceType/values )) )

(defn get-all-placetypes
  ""
  [x]
  (def my-vector (get-placetypes))
  (let [[& the-rest] my-vector]
    (nth the-rest x) ))

(defn string-place-typeII
  ""
  []
  (doseq [n (get-placetypes)]
    (calculate-distance-matrix 2 (define-context API-KEY) n))
  )
(defn calculate-distance-matrix
  ""
  [property-id context place-type]
  ;(def nearby-search-fucntion  )
  (let [r (. (. (. (DistanceMatrixApi/newRequest
                     context)
                   origins (into-array [(coordinates->keys property-id context)] ))
                destinations (into-array [(m/latlng (do-nearby-search property-id context place-type))]))  await)]

    {:distance (-> r
                   .rows
                   first
                   .elements
                   first
                   .distance
                   .humanReadable)
     :duration (-> r
                   .rows
                   first
                   .elements
                   first
                   .duration
                   .humanReadable)})
```

How to I make the `(string-place-typeII)` return the value of `(calculate-distance-matrix)` like this `{:distance "5 km" :duration "2 mins"}` on each iteration?

Comment: can't you use `map` instead of `doseq`? I use `doseq` only when 1. the body of `doseq` produces some side effects, 2. I don't have anything to be returned from there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `map`.

https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/map

```
(defn string-place-typeII
  []
  (map (fn [n] (calculate-distance-matrix 2 (define-context API-KEY) n))
       (get-place-types)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please bookmark [the Clojure Cheatsheet](http://the%20Clojure%20Cheatsheet) and always keep a browser tab open to it.

I think you are looking for the `for` function instead of `doseq`.  `doseq` is meant for side effects (eg printing, db, etc) and always returns `nil`.   `for` returns one item for each time through the loop.

Here is an outline of what you can do:

```
(defn calc_dist [n]
  { :dist (* 2 n) :dur (* 3 n) } )

(defn caller-1 []
  (doseq [n (range 5)]
    (calc_dist n)))

(defn caller-2 []
  (for [n (range 5)]
    (calc_dist n)))

(caller-1) => nil
(caller-2) => [{:dist 0, :dur 0} {:dist 2, :dur 3} {:dist 4, :dur 6} {:dist 6, :dur 9} {:dist 8, :dur 12}]
```

Regarding your `(let [r ...)` expression, please see [the clojure.org section on Java Interop](http://section%20on%20Java%20Interop).  I believe you'll find [the `..` special form](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/_..) is easier to read.  You should may also wish to consider [the `doto` function](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doto).

Comment: Is `forv` a typo Alan?

Answer (score 0):

I would try with replacing the `doseq` with a `for` loop. It will call `calculate-distance-matrix` for each `n` in the `(get-placetypes)`, then the results will be joined as a sequence:

```
(defn string-place-typeII
  ""
  []
  (for [n (get-placetypes)]
    (calculate-distance-matrix 2 (define-context API-KEY) n))
  )
```